# Share cost of activities between participants in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

Say you have a spreadsheet you use to fairly share the cost of activities between people ([example google doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ar9P2Uym3JjvdC1XM1NOVXRSTVpycTZES1gtTm1vUGc&usp=sharing)):

```
       A        B     C     D     E
1    Activity Cost  User1 User2 User3
2    1        100   1     1     1
3    2        50    0     2     0.5
```

So this means: Everyone shares the cost of activity A equally. For acitvity B User1 doesn't pay, User2 pays *2* and User3 pays *0.5* (i.e. User2 pays 80% and User3 20%)

For every row and user (e.g. User1 and row 2) you can easily calculate everything a user has to pay:

```
=C1/SUM($C2:$E2)*$B1
```

But if you want to calculate what every user has to pay you need another matrix with all these formula's and sum them. Can you also calculate what every user has to pay directly in a formula?

Comment: How does 2 and .5 translate to 80% and 20%? What are you trying to accomplish? Your question is a little unclear to me.

Comment: `2/(2+0.5) = 0.8`. It's sharing the cost fairly. User2 pays for 2 people, User3 pays for only "half a person" (e.g. because he only participated half the activity). See the online spreadsheet which seems fairly clear to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can probably be simplified even more, but my suggestion is to use `SUMPRODUCT` in this way:

1. Add a "Total Shares" in Column I to total cols E-H.
2. To calculate the cost per person, and skip the intermediate matrix, you can use the formula below in `E15` and copy across.

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(E2:E4,1/$I2:$I4,$C2:$C4)
   ```

This will, as the name infers, add up a series of products.
The user's # of shares
* 1/ Total Shares (i.e. dividing by total shares)
* the cost of each event

It will do this for matching positions in each array (i.e. values in the same row) and add them up.

Note:   above cell references are to your Google doc, not your above example.

Comment: `1/$I2:$I4` didn't work, but making the `total` column `1/SUM(...)` and using sumproduct on that did work. Thanks!